# While moving the cursor across a vim process open in a tmux session, every now and then, why does it leave a trail of ghost characters - ^[OB, ^[OA?

Tags: vim, tmux

These disappear if I do a page-up and page-down. Why does this happen and how do I rectify it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnMYl.png

I recently fiddled around with my vimrc. Could that be the cause?

UPDATE:
I figured out the cause. I had added to functions that automatically updated the cwd name and the current git branch in my vim statusline. This caused vim to be laggy and everytime it lagged on a up/down/left/right key hit, it printed out the ghost characters ^[OA, etc.
It's possible that stuff got complicated because I was using vim in tmux, but I saw the ghost characters outside tmux also. So, probably not.
I've turned off those two functions in my .vimrc and my vim statusline is presently less awesome than it used to be :(
Wish there's a way out.

Comment: I had a similar problem except h j k l were appearing everywhere. Disabling the git branch name function in status line fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^[OB` and `^[OA` are how your terminal represent `<down>` and `<up>`.

I've seen these (and their friends `^[OC` and `^[OD`) appear in the "command line" or omni-completion menus and during usage of a couple of plugins in vim in tmux.

My solution was to map them to the directional keys:

```
map ^[OA <up>
map ^[OB <down>
map ^[OC <right>
map ^[OD <left>
```

In case you don't know, you must not type `^[` as two characters, you must do `<C-v><Esc>`.

That is, while in `--INSERT--` mode press the **Control** key and the **V** key together then hit the **Escape** key. Doing so will input the correct **single** character that looks like `^[`.

Comment: Edit: Seemed like they had disappeared but they are back again.
`map <C-v><Esc>OA <up>
map <C-v><Esc>OB <down>
map <C-v><Esc>OC <right>
map <C-v><Esc>OD <left>`

This is what I added to my .vimrc.

Comment: Don't know what's wrong. I did exactly as you said this time.
I finally commented off this function that helped me jump to the next line with same indentation, which I had added to my vimrc just before I noticed these ghost characters. That seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is discussed at length on the [Vim Wiki article](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_arrow_keys_that_display_A_B_C_D_on_remote_shell). There seem to be multiple causes, I personally encountered this issue when running vim under tmux.

A solution from there that worked for me and seems less hacky than mapping the keys was the following config:

`set term=cons25`

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without knowing what's in your vimrc, but you can confirm whether it's something in there by starting it up without running it and seeing if it still happens using the following...

`vim -u NONE`

Comment: Hmm.. I don't get those weird ghost characters if I start up with the -u flag. So, I guess it's got something to do with my vimrc. Is there a simple way of figuring out the troublesome part of the vimrc file other than brute force trial-and-error?

Comment: Don't think so, unfortunately. Remember though that every line in your vimrc is just a command that can be run in the program itself, so you don't need to keep editing the file and restarting. Just run the commands one-by-one in a `-u NONE` and see when it breaks.

Before you get started though, I would say to check whether you have the line `set nocompatible` in your vimrc (you probably do, but just in case). If you don't have that, try adding it and see if that fixes things.

Comment: Alright. I did not figure out the cause but I got a solution from @romainl . Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to be using zsh? I had this issue with vim + zsh/oh-my-zsh. Moving back to vanilla bash solved this issue (amongst others) that I was having with vim.