# Arrow keys in vim (linux) in insert mode broken for me

Tags: vim

When I use the arrow keys in vim in insert mode I get letters inserted instead of movement.

- Up produces an A
- Down produces a B
- Left products a D
- Right produces a C

Does anyone know what would cause this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like somthing wrong with your terminal/shell.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 w/ zsh
@balki - they work fine in normal mode

Comment: See [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6988748/546861) and [this one](http://superuser.com/a/432423/60075) (both mines). It looks to be linked with some plugin/$TERM combinations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If these keys work fine in normal mode, but do not in insert then you must have some mappings to the first one or two characters (normally `<Up>` is either `<Esc>[A` (terminals that use CSI) or `<Esc>OA` (xterm)). Try checking out output of

```
verbose imap <Esc>
```

, there should be not much mappings starting with `<Esc>` in insert mode (I have none, for example). I can say, that with arrow keys working normally in insert mode, using

```
inoremap <Esc> <Esc>
```

produces just the same behavior as if you had problems with terminal recognition or had 'compatible' set.

Answer (score 7):

Your `vim` seems to be starting in the `vi` compatibility mode. Do this

- Open Vim editor,
- Get the path of your home directory by typing :`echo $HOME`
- Check if you have .vimrc file in `$HOME` location,(if you don't have create it)
- Add the following line line to `.vimrc` file
  `:set nocompatible`

Find more solutions for the same problem [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_arrow_keys_that_display_A_B_C_D_on_remote_shell) ( Especially if your problem is terminal related, the re-mapping of keys solution might work for you )

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me. Just put it in your .vimrc

```
:set term=cons25
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Vim editor.
2. Get the path of your home directory by typing: `:echo $HOME`.
3. Check if you have .vimrc file in $HOME location, and if you don't have create it.
4. Add the following line line to .vimrc file: `:set nocompatible`

Reference: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_arrow_keys_that_display_A_B_C_D_on_remote_shell

Comment: you may try other solutions on the reference page.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answer here worked for me. I'm in Linux, with konsole/yakuake terminal and tmux. This fix works for me:

```
nnoremap <silent> <ESC>OA <ESC>ki
nnoremap <silent> <ESC>OB <ESC>ji
nnoremap <silent> <ESC>OC <ESC>hi
nnoremap <silent> <ESC>OD <ESC>li
inoremap <silent> <ESC>OA <ESC>ki
inoremap <silent> <ESC>OB <ESC>ji
inoremap <silent> <ESC>OC <ESC>hi
inoremap <silent> <ESC>OD <ESC>li
```